# Use property defined in maven dependency artifact

Tags: maven, properties, dependency-management

Is it possible, to access the properties defined in a dependent maven artificat without making it the parent artifact of current project?
Example:

My 3rd party dependent artifact has the following pom:

```
 <project>
   <groupId>3rd</groupId>
   <artifactId>party</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
   <properties>
     <test>this is a test</test>
   </properties>
 </project>
```

My own project depends on this 3rd party artifacts and wants to reuse the property in some way:

```
 <project>
   <groupId>my</groupId>
   <artifactId>own</artifactId>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>3rd</groupId>
       <artifactId>party</artifactId>
       <version>1</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <properties>
     <mytest>${test} - in my artifact</mytest>
   </properties>
  </project>
```

Comment: What kind of propertie is this what you like to use? For build information or for what? Properties in pom are intended for building purposes and not for runtime usage...

Comment: the property is holding a version for dependency management. The problem is, that the dependency i need is not managed in the dependent project.

Comment: in detail: my depndent pom is creating the property "spring.security.version" and uses it for dependency management. I need an addional dependency, which is not managed in my dependency (so that "import" scope doesnt work), which uses the same "spring.security.version"

Comment: You can simply make a dependency on your project which already has the dependency for spring.security. It will come as a transitive dependency automatically.

Comment: spring.security isnt a dependency at all. its just a property holding the version for various spring security artifacts, like spring-security-core, spring-security-web, spring-security-ldap, ......